# Can I use django as frontend and have a login system with Token Authentication

Tags: django

Well, this question is for the ones who has experience in working with Django.
I'm new to Django and I have been studying Django, still I want to build an webapi with Django as backend and frontend, with a token authentication. Is that possible, and logical? I have been watching tutorial and reading documentation. Everyone who creates an api full django, creates a basic authentication. And, I want to know if is possible to create a more secure authentication with django as frontend. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking: yes, you can do that - but not with django alone. Also don't know every possible solution, but you can do this with the **Django REST framework**.

Here are some links to the documentation:

[Django REST framework - Homepage](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

[Django REST framework - TokenAuthentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication)

I personally use JSON Web Tokens in combination with **Django** and **Django REST framework**:

[Simple JWT](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)